# jquery check the class from variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem that i cannot get a class from a variable in javascript.

```
var li_id = LI_element.id;
if(!($("'#"+li_id+"'").hasClass("abc"))) {
    console.log(LI_element);
}
```

Here, `li_id` gives me id of an element and i want to check that this element has the class `abc` or not. But, when i execute the above command it gives me error that says

```
throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

I assume there is some error in the if statement. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the `msg` of the error? Also you can simply use `$(LI_element).hasClass(...` instead of concatenating a selector together.

Comment: Why you just don't use LI_element to check if hasClass and need to convert a id variable and check if that #id hasClass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the selector you have extra quotes `'`, which shouldn't be there.

Otherwise just use the following syntax:

```
if (!$(LI_element).hasClass("abc")) {
    console.log(LI_element);
}
```